# Task Scheduler Wrapper -DeleteTask- not deleting

Tags: c#, windows-services, taskscheduler

I have a Windows Service installed and a task registered in the Windows TaskScheduler. For managing tasks I am using Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper. What I want to do is, once the service is uninstalled then remove the task. I have tried doing so from both serviceInstaller_BeforeUninstall and serviceInstaller_AfterUninstall and no success so far. Below see the code.

```
private void serviceInstaller_BeforeUninstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{            
    Recycler.RemoveTask("taskX");
}
```

And the Recycler class is:

```
public class Recycler
{
    public static void RemoveTask(string taskName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(taskName)) return;

        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            var task = ts.FindTask(taskName);
            if (task != null)
            {
                ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask(task.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the current behavior? Are you seeing any exceptions in the logs? You may have permissions issues that need addressing.

Comment: No exception has been thrown. I'm running the service local and I'm the admin. I tried debugging the service and when Recycler.RemoveTask is called outside the events it works.